# How do I test Angularjs factory stubbing $http?

Tags: http, testing, angularjs, factory

I have this factory called `Songs` which fetches songs each second from an API:

```
angular.module('pearlJam')
  .factory('Songs', function($http, $timeout, Config){
      var response = {list: []};
      var onSuccess = function(result){
        response.list = result.data.data;
        $timeout(poller, Config.pollingTimeout);
      };

      var poller = function(){
        $http.get('api/songs.json', Config.httpOptions).then(onSuccess);
      };

      poller();
      return {all: response};
    });
```

I would like to test it, and I tried it is shown bellow but I think I inject Service in a wrong way. When I try to run the test it outputs **Error: No pending request to flush !**.It is like it's not making http calls.

```
describe('Songs', function(){
    var httpStub, localService;
    beforeEach(module('pearlJam'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, Songs){
      httpStub = _$httpBackend_;
      localService = Songs;
    }));

    it('lists all songs', function(){
      var httpResponse = { data: [1]};
      httpStub.whenGET('api/songs.json').respond(httpResponse);

      var serviceResponse = localService.all;
      httpStub.flush();

      expect(serviceResponse).toBe([1]);
    });
  });
```

Comment: What's `Streams`? Shouldn't it be `Songs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expectGET creates a new expectation, telling angular to respond with the given object when a GET request is made to /api/songs.json. It's just registering what it should do but no GET request are fired here.

Because you immediately invoke the poller function in your service, the http request will fire when the service is loaded.

And you have to stub the response before the http request is fired (i.e. before the service is loaded). Load pearlJam module -> register expectation with expectGET -> load Songs service

Here I stripped down your code to the most important part but re-injecting the Config and $timeout services should work as well http://plnkr.co/edit/lbkxjTJbEjEXIzbyNPVF?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

The `$httpBackend.flush()` method works only for requests expectations like `expectGET`.

The `whenGET` method allows you to mock the backend and hijack the request to respond something special but it's doesn't count for the flush.

If you call `flush()` without expectations, it throws the error you're encountering.

Comment: I tried with `expectGET` or even leaving `whenGET` with no `flush()` either way it is still failing.